# Making a 3-column grid with flexible middle

Tags: html, css, dynamic-columns

I solved a problem I was having and I thought the solution might help others.

I needed to have a 3 column layout with fixed left and right columns and a flexible center. It needed to fill the space between the columns, no matter how it changed, so it couldn't be fixed. It's strange and doesn't seem like it'll work, but it's like magic.

I modified what was put together here http://jsfiddle.net/qx32C/36/

Here's a demo on my 3-column version http://jsfiddle.net/chazthetic/qx32C/294/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="right">lkasjdfl;<br />kjasdf;<br />lkjas;<br />ldfkjdjf</div>
<div class="lineContainer">
    <div class="left">lkasjdfl;<br />kjasdf;<br />ldfkja;<br />sldfjk;laksdjf</div>
    <div class="middle">lkasjdfl;<br />kjasdf;<br />lkjas;</div>
</div>
```

​

CSS

```
.lineContainer {
    overflow: hidden; /* clear the float */
    border: 1px solid #000
}
.lineContainer div {
    height: auto;
} 
.left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #000
}
.middle {
    margin-left: 100px;
    background: #ccc
}
.right {
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
​
```

Answer (score -1):

You should just float the middle left as well. This will allow the elements to all be dependent on the size of the browser.

```
.left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #000
}
.middle {
    float:left;
    background: #ccc
}
.right {
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
```

​